Shaded columnar (irish) yew: to hedge or not to hedge
They are now 15 years old and never cut into shape for a hedge. There is not much light for them either. I would love to have them into a hedge, at least have the walkway clear of their branches so the do not interfere with people's heads as they walk by. Should I attempt to cut them back for a hedge or better just tie them up ?



Yew grows rather slowly. You can cut it back, and it will fill in, but it may take 5-10 years to do so. If you can cut back without removing all the foliage where you cut, recovery may be somewhat faster, and it will look a bit better as you wait.
I have drastically cut back a very overgrown yew hedge that was allowed to get  way out of line. Thus, the cut sections had essentially no foliage.  The part with the most removed did take about 10 years to fill back in. But it did, eventually, do so. Areas that were not cut so far were able to regenerate somewhat faster, and were not starting from nothing to do so.
So, if you are patient, cutting it back will work. If you can finesse it so that you leave some foliage on there, then keep shaving that back further as more comes in behind it, you might be able to get it where you'd like it faster without it being a bare eyesore for a long time. Aim for a tapering shape to allow more light in at the top where the building is and let that light get to the base by having the base a bit wider, within the limits of letting people pass unscathed.
If, as it appears, it is trapped between a building and a fence, it's going to have a hard time ever being a nice hedge on the bottom, and might better be cut right back to the trunks until it's above the fence. Whether or not you bother to shape it at that point is up to you, if that means it's out of people's way. If you'd like a nicer hedge all the way to the ground, consider changing the fence to let more light in. If topping it, I'd go for 6 inches or so below where you want the top of the hedge, not cutting it way below that level. Then stay on top  of trimming the new growth.

Lucky you, having a yew hedge. That's quite a desirable feature to have in your garden. Yew is a remarkable plant, being shade tolerant and one of the few conifers that will regrow when cut hard back. According to the RHS website here:

If your [yew] hedge has developed bare stems at the base, you can coppice
it, to encourage new growth lower down. This involves cutting the
plants down to within 15–20cm (6–8in) of the ground in early spring.
They will then produce multiple stems and fresh foliage. However, this
is a slow process, and the hedge will take several years to recover.

I'd be tempted to do just that. Coppice the hedge and be patient. Keep the surrounding soil weed and grass free to give the yews the best possible chance to regenerate. Read the RHS article.

Yews make excellent hedging material as they will bud out from old wood.  However these specimens have been allowed to grow as they will for some time and it appears the foliage adjacent to the house is in a low light situation due to the overhang of the house and the fence..
So, you could take a hedge trimmer and cut them back to free up the walkway but I don't think they are going to look very nice for a long time.
If it was my place I would remove them.  The light is too low to get a nice looking hedge.
